# Is an iPhone backup of 1st January 2001 midnight real?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore

A friend broke an iPhone (see [Recover data from broken iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408036/recover-data-from-broken-iphone)) and the Mac computer shows an "unknown" backup dated 1st January 2001, at midnight, long before acquiring the phone or the computer:

[image: Backup from 1st January 2001]

Restoring the backup to a new phone fails because it is encrypted and the owner does not remember either backing up or choosing a password.

The location of iPhone backups at `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/` (from [this thread](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215)) shows a tree of folders created on 7th November 2020:

[image: Folders in backup]

What is this iPhone backup, and is it real?

Comment: The directory structure looks real, hard to say more.

Comment: "Restoring the backup to a computer fails" ?? How does one restore a backup to a computer?Anyway, if an iPhone backup is encrypted then without the password it is of no use whatsoever.

Comment: @Tetsujin I had a typo, it's "restore the backup to a new phone."

Comment: OK, correction makes more sense - however, without the password, there's absolutely no way into it.

Comment: Sure, we need the password, and the date would help with that. The backup cannot be from 1st January 2001, maybe the computer had a date reset at the time of backup. Could the backup be from 7th November 2020, or some other date?

Comment: The last backup date is the modified date, ie today. The created date is the first backup of that device. The device folder affc8e… remains attached to that device 'forever'.

Comment: Check iTunes Prefs - Devices panel - it should show all backed up devices & their most recent backup dates… https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv3Wy.png  BTW, the backup password isn't the same as any other password anywhere - it's entirely separate from the device or the Mac or any iCloud account. It exists only unto itself.